# Concatenation with non-blocking assignment

Tags: verilog, hdl, state-machines, rtl

I'm teaching myself Verilog with HDLbits and tackling [this problem](https://hdlbits.01xz.net/wiki/Exams/ece241_2013_q4). According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111861/direction-of-verilog-concatenation), assignment with the LHS of the expression as a concatenation should work. In practice I've used this many times before. However, when I assign a wire to a concatenation and then use a non-blocking assignment on that wire, the wire is not driven.

```
module top_module (
input clk,
input reset,
input [3:1] s,
output fr3,
output fr2,
output fr1,
output dfr
); 
parameter lowest = 3'b000, aboveS1 = 3'b001, aboveS2 = 3'b011, aboveS3 = 3'b111;
parameter hf = 3'b111, mf = 3'b011, lf = 3'b001, zf = 3'b000;
reg [2:0] state, next_state;
wire [2:0] flowrate = {fr3,fr2,fr1}; //problem area

always @ * begin
    next_state = {s[3],s[2],s[1]};
end

always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if(reset) begin
        state <= lowest;
        {fr3,fr2,fr1} <= hf;
        dfr <= 1'b1;
    end else begin
        if(next_state != state)
            dfr <= next_state < state;
        else
            dfr <= dfr;
        case(next_state)
            aboveS1 : flowrate <= mf; //problem area
            aboveS2 : flowrate <= lf;
            aboveS3 : flowrate <= zf;
            default : flowrate <= hf;
        endcase
        state <= next_state;
    end
end
endmodule
```

The above code fails as fr3, fr2, and fr1 are stuck at ground. But when the case statement is changed to the following:

```
aboveS1 : {fr3,fr2,fr1} <= mf;
aboveS2 : {fr3,fr2,fr1} <= lf;
aboveS3 : {fr3,fr2,fr1} <= zf;
default : {fr3,fr2,fr1} <= hf;
```

The code works fine, and the outputs are driven. Why does this occur?

There is also this warning thrown by Quartus which I'm sure is related:

```
Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at top_module.v(13):
object "flowrate" assigned a value but never read File:             
/home/h/work/hdlbits.2001977/top_module.v Line: 13
Warning (13024): Output pins are stuck at VCC or GND
Warning (13410): Pin "fr3" is stuck at VCC File: 
/home/h/work/hdlbits.2001977/top_module.v Line: 5
Warning (13410): Pin "fr2" is stuck at VCC File: 
/home/h/work/hdlbits.2001977/top_module.v Line: 6
Warning (13410): Pin "fr1" is stuck at VCC File: 
/home/h/work/hdlbits.2001977/top_module.v Line: 7
```

The following replacements in the upper area also break:

```
wire [2:0] flowrate;
assign {fr3,fr2,fr1} = flowrate;
```

and

```
wire [2:0] flowrate;
assign flowrate = {fr3,fr2,fr1};
```

*Edit: clarified error a bit more*

Comment: FYI, SystemVerilog has the `alias` and `let` constructs that both give you the bidirectional semantics you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks dave_59, I'm trying to familiarize myself with the idiodyncrasies of Verilog before I move on to SystemVerilog, but maybe I should just focus on the latter and not waste the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main issues:

1. Assignments are make to the LHS (Left-Hand-Side).
2. Anything assigned by an always block needs to be a non-net type. `flowrate` should be a `reg` type instead of a `wire`.

Therefore:

```
wire [2:0] flowrate = {fr3,fr2,fr1};
```

Should be:

```
reg [2:0] flowrate;
assign {fr3,fr2,fr1} = flowrate;
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be expecting that the declaration

```
wire [2:0] flowrate = {fr3,fr2,fr1};
```

creates some sort of bidirectional equivalence between `flowrate` and the three outputs, such that assigning to `flowrate` is in effect an assignment to the outputs. There's nothing about the semantics of the Verilog language that would support this.

Instead, you would need to do something more like:

```
wire [2:0] flowrate;
assign {fr3,fr2,fr1} = flowrate;
```

Comment: Well, that breaks because there are multiple drivers for flowrate then, in the sequential logic and the assign statement

Comment: Thanks for your help, I should've noted that I originally wrote and tested it with assign statements outside of the declaration, I must've accidentally changed that line when I was editing it to post on SO.